# different between "SDK Tools Only" and "All Android Studio Packages"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to download android studio from here.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
there is two options here
   SDK Tools Only
and
   All Android Studio Packages

whats different between this two options?

Answer (score 3):

"All Android Studio Packages" include Android Studio and the SDK tools. "SDK Tools Only" is only the SDK tools. "SDK Tools Only" would be useful in scenarios like:

- You are using an IDE other than Android Studio, or
- You are setting up some server to build Android apps, such as a continuous integration server

Comment: I'm using eclipse with latest SDK and now i want migrate to Android studio. So, should I download again all SDK? What is the procedure ??   @CommonsWare

Comment: @ShaishavJogani: Sorry, but I have not attempted that migration in over a year, and I always kept my Android SDK maintained separately from the IDE. I do not know what the recommended process is for you.